# How to train CoreNlp to detect names in Python?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I'm using **CoreNLP** technology in Python, and during my tests, I noticed that several times certain names were not detected by CoreNLP, so I would like to know how I could train CoreNLP to detect these **names** as **person** in **Python**.

My program is based on: https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python